# ¿Cómo puedo crear políticas de seguridad a un atributo en OpenLDAP que no es la contraseña?

Tags: directorioactivo, ldap, openldap

Estoy utilizando [OpenLDAP 2.4.40](http://www.openldap.org/). Tengo un atributo llamado `claveTelefonica` el cual debe tener las políticas de seguridad de la contraseña (historial, caducidad, longitud, etc...) pero con otros valores. Actualmente utilizo el `pwdPoliciy` para la contraseña, quisiera uno para el otro atributo.

¿Es posible realizarlo? ¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?